# Double tap gesture on phone Screen

Tags: java, android, gesture-recognition

I want to know can we have some thing in android to recognize double tap action on SCREEN itself.

I found lot of code related to double tap gesture but didn't find for SCREEN. Please let me know if it is there in API.

It is like we click on screen of the mobile and it will start the action like in windows phone when we double click on phone screen it will come into on mode form steady mode.

I am using this code for double tap gesture.

```
package a.b.c;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements OnDoubleTapListener,OnGestureListener
{
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction()==1)
        {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onDoubleTap", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction()==1)
        {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onDoubleTapEvent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction()==1)
        {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onSingleTapConfirmed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Did you solved this ? If yes then can you please help me my requirements are same.

Comment: yes you can use third party application/launcher for the same.!!Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your activity..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener
{    
    private LinearLayout main;    
    private TextView viewA;

    private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);

        main = new LinearLayout(this);
        main.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        main.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(320,480));

        viewA = new TextView(this);
        viewA.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        viewA.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        viewA.setTextSize(16);
        viewA.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(320,80));
        main.addView(viewA);

        setContentView(main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
    {
     return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
     viewA.setText("-" + "DOWN" + "-");
     return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
     viewA.setText("-" + "FLING" + "-");
     return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
     viewA.setText("-" + "LONG PRESS" + "-");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
    {
     viewA.setText("-" + "SCROLL" + "-");
     return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e)
    {
     viewA.setText("-" + "SHOW PRESS" + "-");
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)    
    {
     viewA.setText("-" + "SINGLE TAP UP" + "-");
     return true;
    }

 @Override
 public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
  viewA.setText("-" + "DOUBLE TAP" + "-");
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
  viewA.setText("-" + "DOUBLE TAP EVENT" + "-");
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
  viewA.setText("-" + "SINGLE TAP CONFORMED" + "-");
  return true;
 }
}
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Boss its not Working what i want is user double click on the screen and then i will do so operation on it.!!!:)

Comment: What if I want just double tap stuff and not worry about all the other ones?